# How to deal with the lack of `latest_receipt_info` in a subscription receipt?

Tags: ios, app-store

I have built a server endpoint to validate the receipts of my users. My users are on iOS devices and can purchase a subscription from the AppStore.

Today I have noticed in the logs that some users have a JSON receipt that lacks `latest_receipt_info`:

```
{
  'receipt': {
    'receipt_type': 'Production',
    'adam_id': 13052xxxx,
    'app_item_id': 13052xxxx,
    'bundle_id': 'com.xxx.xxx.vpn',
    'application_version': '2',
    'download_id': 7504221xxxx,
    'version_external_identifier': 8303xxxx,
    'receipt_creation_date': '2019-02-20 05:27:15 Etc/GMT',
    'receipt_creation_date_ms': '1550640435000',
    'receipt_creation_date_pst': '2019-02-19 21:27:15 America/Los_Angeles',
    'request_date': '2019-02-20 06:53:53 Etc/GMT',
    'request_date_ms': '1550645633891',
    'request_date_pst': '2019-02-19 22:53:53 America/Los_Angeles',
    'original_purchase_date': '2019-02-11 09:03:16 Etc/GMT',
    'original_purchase_date_ms': '1549875796000',
    'original_purchase_date_pst': '2019-02-11 01:03:16 America/Los_Angeles',
    'original_application_version': '2',
    'in_app': []
  },
  'status': 0,
  'environment': 'Production'
}
```

In my server endpoint I'm rejecting any receipt that doesn't have the `latest_receipt_info`:

```
def verify_receipt(receipt):
    r = requests.post(config.APPLE_STORE_URL, json=Subscription.produce_receipt_with_credentials(receipt))
    now = datetime.utcnow()
    if 'latest_receipt_info' in r.json():
        for item in r.json()['latest_receipt_info']:
            dt, tz = item['expires_date'].rsplit(maxsplit=1)
            expires_date = datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone(tz))
            expires_date = expires_date.astimezone(pytz.utc)
            expires_date = expires_date.replace(tzinfo=None)
            if expires_date > now:
                return True, expires_date, r.json()['latest_receipt'], item
    else:
        current_app.logger.info('latest_receipt_info not found: %s', r.json())
    return False, None, None, None
```

But it seems I might be mistaken in my approach, since the documentation says this about status:

> Status: Either 0 if the receipt is valid, or one of the error codes
>   listed in Table 2-1.

In other words the status is 0, means it's valid.  But I don't see any expiry_date or anything I could verify the receipt's expiration date.

I can't find anything in the documentation.  What should I do? Should I trust any receipt with status 0 automatically?

The documentation also says this about `latest_receipt_info`, which isn't clear to me:

> latest_receipt_info : Only returned for receipts containing
>   auto-renewable subscriptions.

But every subscription on the app store is automatically renewable unless the user explicitly cancels it. What gives that those receipts don't have a `latest_receipt_info`?  Does it mean they have cancelled it and are in the final cycle?  Thank you for your advice.

Comment: You always have a receipt, even if it is only for the initial download of the app. Even free apps have a receipt. The receipt you have shown is valid for the case where no in-app purchase have been made

Comment: @Paulw11 that makes sense to me. Thank you for clarifying this. I couldn't see that from the docs.